# Apps Script: Collect Form Input and Display Today's Total

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

First time poster here: I've created a web app in Apps Script where the user enters:

- Date
- Food
- Quantity

...then the associated 'health points' are calculated and added to a spreadsheet in Google Sheets.

What I want to do is calculate and display the day's total and then recalculate and display whenever the form is submitted.  I'm still a newer JS user, so I'm cheating a bit by calculating in Google Sheets.  Here's what that formula looks like:

> =sum(ArrayFormula(if(today()-1=Data!A:A,Data!B:B,0)))

..then I'm passing that as a template value.  That works when loading the page, but I would like it to update whenever the form is submitted.

Do you have ideas on how to calculate today's total using a script instead of Sheets and recalculating/displaying when the form is submitted?

Update: I've attached the code. And here's the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pXtOAnVJOkz1DGKir79pxoMUG85LPSfoN4SSVUk0a1k/edit?usp=sharing

```js
function doGet(request) {
  var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pXtOAnVJOkz1DGKir79pxoMUG85LPSfoN4SSVUk0a1k/edit#gid=0";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Points");
  var total = ws.getRange(1,1,1,1).getValue();
  var remaining = 25-total;
  Logger.log(total);
  Logger.log(remaining);
  t.total = total;
  t.remaining = remaining;
  return t.evaluate();
}

function getLast() {
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pXtOAnVJOkz1DGKir79pxoMUG85LPSfoN4SSVUk0a1k/edit#gid=0";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  var last = ws.getLastRow();
  Logger.log(last);
}

/* @Include JavaScript and CSS Files */
function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}

/* @Process Form */
function processForm(formObject) {
   
  // (Calories * .0305) + (Sat Fat * .275) + (Sugar * .12) - (Protein * .098)
  
  var smartpointsServing = Math.round((formObject.calories * .0305) + (formObject.satfat * .275) + (formObject.sugar * .12) - (formObject.protein * .098));  
//  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(formObject.today), "GMT-6", "MM/dd/yyyy");
    
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pXtOAnVJOkz1DGKir79pxoMUG85LPSfoN4SSVUk0a1k/edit#gid=0";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);    
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Foods");
  var ws2 = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  var newFoodHp = smartpointsServing*formObject.quantity;
  
  if (formObject.new_food_name !== ""){
  ws.appendRow([formObject.new_food_name,
               smartpointsServing,
               formObject.serving_size_no,
               formObject.serving_size_unit,
               formObject.calories,
               formObject.satfat,
               formObject.sugar,
               formObject.protein]);  
  
   ws2.appendRow([formObject.today,
                 newFoodHp,
                 formObject.food_name,
                 formObject.quantity]);}
  
  else {
  ws2.appendRow([formObject.today,
                 formObject.smartpoints,
                 formObject.food_name,
                 formObject.quantity]);
                         }  
  
}

function getSmartPoints(foodLookup){
  
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pXtOAnVJOkz1DGKir79pxoMUG85LPSfoN4SSVUk0a1k/edit#gid=0";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Foods");
  var data = ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow()-1, 2).getValues();
  
  var foodList = data.map(function(r){ return r[0]; });
  var smartpointsPerServing = data.map(function(r){ return r[1]; });
  
  var position = foodList.indexOf(foodLookup);
  if (position >-1){
     return smartpointsPerServing[position];  
  } else {
    return 'Food Not Found';
  }
  
}

function returnDropDownArray() {
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pXtOAnVJOkz1DGKir79pxoMUG85LPSfoN4SSVUk0a1k/edit#gid=0";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Foods");
  var array = ws.getRange(2,1,ws.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues().sort();
  Logger.log(array);
  return ws.getRange(2,1,ws.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues().sort();  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      
      <!--Install Bootstrap-->
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
      
    <?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>       
    
    <style>
body {
  color: blue;
}
</style>
    
    </head>
    <body>
    <p id="date"></p>
        <div class="container">
            
                        <form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
                        <h1><b>Health Points</b></h1>

                        <div class = "row">
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                                <label for="today">Date</label>
                                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="today" name="today" required>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <label for="food_name">Food Name:</label><br>
                                <select class="form-control" id="food_name" name="food_name" value="Select Food" required>
                                </select>
                             </div>
                       
                       <div class="col-md-4">
                       <div class="form-check">
                       <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="add" name="add">
                       <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">
                       Add New Food?
                       </label>
                       </div>
                       </div></div>
                       
                       <div class="row">
                         <div class="col-md-4">
                           <label for="quantity">Quantity:</label><br>
                           <input id="quantity" type="number" step=".5" value="1" name="quantity">                           
                         </div>
                        </div><br>
                        
                        <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input id="smartpoints" type="text" placeholder="Health Points" name="smartpoints" readonly>                        
                        </div>
                        </div>                        
                                               
                <!--        <br>
                        <div id="templateTotal"><p>Today's Total:  <strong><?= total ?>/25</strong><br>
                        Points Remaining: <strong><?= remaining ?></strong></p></div> -->
                        
                   <!-- Start section for adding foods -->
                        
                      <div id="addfood" style="display:none;">
                      <br>  
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                      <div class="card">                      
                      <div class="card-header">
                      Add a Food
                      </div>
                      <div class="container">
                       <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <label for="new_food_name">New Food Name:</label><br>
                                <input type="text" id="new_food_name" name="new_food_name">                                
                             </div>                                                   
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <label for="serving_size_no">Serving Size #:</label>
                                <input type="number" id="serving_size_no" name="serving_size_no" step=".25">                                
                             </div>                                                   
                        </div>
                        
                         <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <label for="serving_size_unit">Serving Size Unit:</label>
                                <input list="serving_size_unit_list" id="serving_size_unit" name="serving_size_unit">
                                <datalist id="serving_size_unit_list">
                                <option value="Cup(s)">
                                <option value="Ounce(s)">
                                <option value="Tbsp(s)">
                                <option value="Tsp(s)">
                                <option value="Gram(s)">
                                </datalist>
                             </div>                                                   
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <label for="calories">Calories:</label>
                                <input type="number" id="calories" name="calories" step="1">                                
                             </div>                                                   
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <label for="satfat">Saturated Fat:</label>
                                <input type="number" id="satfat" name="satfat">                                
                             </div>                                                   
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <label for="satfat">Sugar:</label>
                                <input type="number" id="sugar" name="sugar">                                
                             </div>                                                   
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <label for="protein">Protein:</label>
                                <input type="number" id="protein" name="protein">                                
                             </div>                                                   
                        </div><br>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        </div></div><br>
                        
                   <!-- End section for adding foods -->

                        <div class="col-md-4">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                                              
                       </form>
        <div id="output"></div>
        </div>
            
        
        
                        <script type="text/javascript">                        
                                         
                         document.getElementById("add").onchange = function(){
                         if (document.getElementById("add").checked) {
                         addfood.style.display = "block";                         
                         } else {
                         addfood.style.display = "none";
                         }
                         
                         };

                        
                        document.getElementById('food_name').onclick = function() {
                        var foodLookup = this.value;
                        
                        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(populateSmartpoints).getSmartPoints(foodLookup);
                        
                        function populateSmartpoints(smartpointsPerServing){ 
                        var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity').value;
                        document.getElementById('smartpoints').value=smartpointsPerServing*quantity;
                        };
                        
                        }
                         
                        // Run function afterPageLoads once the page has loaded
                        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",afterPageLoads);
                        
                        // Get drop down array for food names if that function is successful
                        function afterPageLoads() {
                             google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(afterDropDownArrayReturned).returnDropDownArray();
                              
                        }              
                                              
                        
                        // Populate food name drop down with array from Google Sheets
                        
                        function afterDropDownArrayReturned(arrayOfArrays) {
                             var item = document.getElementById("food_name");
                             console.log(item);
                             arrayOfArrays.forEach(function(r){
                                  var option = document.createElement("option");
                                  option.textContent = r[0];
                                  item.appendChild(option);
                        });
                        }
                        
                        // Update Smart Points if quantity is updated
                        document.getElementById('quantity').onchange = function() {
                         var sp = document.getElementById('smartpoints').value;
                         var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity').value;
                         document.getElementById('smartpoints').value=sp*quantity;
                         
                         
                         }
                         
                         // Update food name if new food is added
                         document.getElementById('new_food_name').onchange = function() {
                         var newOption = document.getElementById('new_food_name').value;
                         if (newOption !==""){
                         var item = document.getElementById("food_name");
                         var option = document.createElement("option");
                         option.textContent = newOption;
                         item.appendChild(option);                         
                         var val = item.value;
                         item.value = newOption;                                                  
                         }
                         }
                         
                         //Set today as the default date                         
                                                
                         n =  new Date();
                         y = n.getFullYear();
                         m = n.getMonth() + 1;
                         d = n.getDate();
                         document.getElementById("today").value = y + "-" + m + "-" + d;
                        
                        //Reload Page
                        
                        
                         
                        </script>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [mcve] and [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Comment: Can you share a copy of the sheet and the script you are using to get a better sense of how is this working?

Comment: Here's the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pXtOAnVJOkz1DGKir79pxoMUG85LPSfoN4SSVUk0a1k/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

This will sum column B in a linked sheet to a form from row 2 to the submitted row.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  const vals=sh.getRange(2,2,e.range.getRow()-1).getValues().flat();
  let sum=vals.reduce(function(a,c){return a+=c;},0);
  Logger.log(sum);
}
```

Remember the trigger requires an installable trigger.

Comment: I've added the code and link to the sheet above. Will this work with a form created in HTML and not in Google Forms?

Comment: No. If you're building a webapp you can pass the form through google.script.run or post it to a doGet() or doPost().

Comment: That did what I needed it to. Thanks.